# Have an array of objects, need to add new object. How do I check if only one of key: value pairs exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

please advise. I have this:

```
var x =[ { id: '1', item: 'item1', price: 'price1' }, 
         { id: '2', item: 'item2', price: 'price2' }
       ]
```

I need to be able to keep adding new objects to this Array, but with only condition, only `id` should be unique.. 
So I should not be able to add object like

```
{id: '2', item: 'item3', price: 'price3'}
```

And be able to add something like

```
{id: '3', item: 'item2', price: 'price3'}
```

How to perform check for that condition of mine?

Basically, all the rest but `id` could repeat.
And no `jQuery` please.

thank you in advance!!!

Comment: what does actually not work?

Comment: Easy: keep track of ids already in array and check before adding new object.

Comment: Nina, at the moment it is possible to add new object with an id that is already belongs to an object, eg id: 2

Comment: @EFFG That's because you do not have any conditions before adding.

Comment: Suresh, you've done it for me. Thank you, mate.. Why didn't I think of mapping ids first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the id's into an array and then check the given object id is there in that array or not

for ex :

```
var allids = x.map(obj => obj.id); // Es 6

if(allids.indexOf(currentObj.id) > -1) {   
  // exist. don't add.
}else {    
 // add
}
```

If you don't want ES6 line,

```
var allids = x.map(function(obj) {return obj.id;});
```

Comment: Instead of `map` and `indexOf` you could just use `find`.

Comment: you also need to update `allids` after adding new object.

Comment: @RohitAgrawal This will be inside adding function so executes each time.

Comment: @Xufox But I found indexOf is more performance friendly and `includes` is the best https://jsperf.com/js-multiloop

Answer (score 1):

```
function addObjectToArray(arr,obj){
    var findEle = arr.find(function(o){
        return o.id === obj.id;
    })
    if(findEle === undefined){
        arr.push(obj);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

filter to the rescue

```js
var x =[ { id: '1', item: 'item1', price: 'price1' }, 
         { id: '2', item: 'item2', price: 'price2' }
       ]
 
addToX(x,{ id: '2', item: 'item2', price: 'price2' }) // will throw duplicates
addToX(x,{ id: '4', item: 'item2', price: 'price2' }) // NO duplicates

function addToX(obj,newObj) {
   let duplicates = obj.filter((eachObj) => {      
        return eachObj["id"] == newObj["id"]
   })
   console.log(duplicates, "duplicates")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use existing ids as dictionary

```
var x =[ { id: '1', item: 'item1', price: 'price1' }, 
         { id: '2', item: 'item2', price: 'price2' }
       ]
var exisingIds = x.reduce(function(res,obj){
  res[obj.id]=true
  return res;
},{})


function add2(item){
  if(!exisingIds[item.id]){
    x.push(item)
    exisingIds[item.id]=true;
  }
}
add2({ id: '3', item: 'item3', price: 'price3' })// will be added 
add2({ id: '3', item: 'item3', price: 'price3' }) // this will not
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Good one. I found findIndex is the slowest function among all others we have https://jsperf.com/js-multiloop

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lodash's groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) for this.

e.g.

```
var x = [ 
         { id: '1', item: 'item1', price: 'price1' }, 
         { id: '2', item: 'item2', price: 'price2' }
       ];

const addToX = (object) => {
    if(!_.groupBy(x, 'id')[object.id]){
        x.push(object);
    }
}
```

You can store the `groupBy` object initially if you don't want to calculate that over run time and make an entry to groupBy object too or you just want to have groupBy'ed object initially rather making an array of objects.